# Get a list of classes and ids used in HTML project

Tags: html, css, netbeans

Is it possible to get a list of all the classes/ids used in a HTML project?

The project that I'm working on has 18 HTML pages (JSP to be fair), I want to know which classes / ids are used on each page.

For example: `<div class="div-class" id="div-id">` has the class `"div-class"` and the id `"div-id"`. I do not want to manually search each page and write down all the classes / ids that I found.

Is there a tool that can do this for me?

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 as the IDE, so if it is possible to do this with NetBeans that would be great!

Comment: Write a java class that will scan the folder for html/jsp pages and then use a regex to identify pattern for id and class. You can get the page wise list of ids & classes.

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya I have never done that, could you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans don't support for this functionalty as far as I know. I'm providing a java class file which you can run in order to get this info.

1. Create a folder named html inside C directory. Put all your html/jsp files inside html directory.
   [image]
2. Run this java class file

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.nio.charset.Charset;
   import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Path;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   public class HtmlIdsAndClasses {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           String path = "C:\\html";

           scanFiles(path);
       }

       private static void scanFiles(String pathLocation) {

           try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(pathLocation))) {
               for (Path path : directoryStream) {

                   HtmlPageInfo pageInfo = new HtmlPageInfo();
                   List<String> classList = new ArrayList<String>();
                   List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
                   pageInfo.setPageName(path.getFileName().toString());
                   pageInfo.setClassList(classList);
                   pageInfo.setIdList(idList);
                   getAllIds(path, pageInfo);
                   getAllClasses(path, pageInfo);
                   System.out.println(pageInfo);
               }
           } catch (IOException ex) {}
       }

       private static void getAllClasses(Path file, HtmlPageInfo pageInfo) {

           Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("class=\"([-A-Za-z_ ]*)\"");
           Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
           BufferedReader reader = null;
           try {

               reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset);
               String line = null;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                   Matcher classMatcher = classPattern.matcher(line);
                   while(classMatcher.find()) {
                       String classGroup = classMatcher.group(1);
                       for(String cls : classGroup.split(" ")) {
                           pageInfo.getClassList().add(cls);
                       }
                   }
               }
           } 
           catch (IOException x) {
               System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
           }
           finally {

               if(reader != null) {
                   try {
                       reader.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       private static void getAllIds(Path file, HtmlPageInfo pageInfo) {

           Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("id=\"([-A-Za-z_]*)\"");
           Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
           BufferedReader reader = null;
           try {

               reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset);
               String line = null;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                   Matcher idMatcher = idPattern.matcher(line);
                   while(idMatcher.find()) {
                       String id = idMatcher.group(1);
                       pageInfo.getIdList().add(id);
                   }
               }
           } 
           catch (IOException x) {
               System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
           }
           finally {

               if(reader != null) {
                   try {
                       reader.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }

   class HtmlPageInfo {

       private String pageName;
       private List<String> idList;
       private List<String> classList;
       public String getPageName() {
           return pageName;
       }
       public void setPageName(String pageName) {
           this.pageName = pageName;
       }
       public List<String> getIdList() {
           return idList;
       }
       public void setIdList(List<String> idList) {
           this.idList = idList;
       }
       public List<String> getClassList() {
           return classList;
       }
       public void setClassList(List<String> classList) {
           this.classList = classList;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {

           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.append("[Page - ");
           sb.append(pageName);
           sb.append("]");
           sb.append("\n\t[IDs - ");
           sb.append("(" + idList.size() + ")]\n\t\t");
           for(String id : idList) {
               sb.append(id + ",");
           }
           sb.append("\n\t[Classes ");
           sb.append("(" + classList.size() + ")]\n\t\t");
           for(String cls : classList) {
               sb.append(cls + ",");
           }
           sb.append("]\n\n");

           return sb.toString();
       }
   }
   ```
3. You will get the output in console as shown in the image below.
   [image]